# How to hide div when user goes to the page with dynamic route?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I need to hide div when user goes to the page with dynamic route . How to detect that user on dynamic route?

```
aside.swiper-side_left(v-show = `[$route.path !== "/worklist/:id"]`)
```

router

```
    {
      path: "/worklist/:id",
      name: "worklistDynamic",
      component: worklistDynamic,
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Define a name in vue router like `{ path: '/worklist/:id', name: 'worklist'}`
2. Now access the name using `$route.name !== 'worklist'`

Comment: I have already defined router. So It should be like this?
     v-show = "$route.name !== 'worklistDynamic'"

Comment: Made the changes